# How to show dynamic label on image view programmatically in Swift 2

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiimageview, swift2, uilabel

I have a view controller which contains 5 image views which I connected them to a class which controls the functions and actions for them! but I need to show dynamic UI Label on them, in the right bottom corner of each one, but don't know how to do that. 
This is my current view controller: 
[image]

But I want to make it look like this: 
[image]

UPDATE : 
My problem in Xcode if I try to add the label view in the story board it adds the label after image view not on it: 
[image]

Comment: what's the problem?  Have you tried adding the labels in xcode? Are they not visible, not updating, not showing mixed fonts?

tells us the problem, tell us what you've done, and show us some code

Comment: I have a stack view in my view controller and i've put 5 image view in it. I want to add 5 label to them but xcode is not allowing me to drop label view on image view it add the label view after image view not on it. i'll update my post in a minute and you can understand what i mean. I asked here to figure a way to add a label on the image view .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to recreate your problem - and I found a solution!

If you add an empty UIView first, you can add the image and the label to that view.

You end up with a stack of UIView, each one containing an image and a label, and you can position the label anywhere you want within the UIView

[image: StackView in Xcode]

Comment: You mean I remove my current view and put and image view in it and again add label view ? without using stack view ?

Comment: keep the stackview - add 5 UIViews.  Add a UIImageView and UILabel to each one of the UIViews, and it will look just the same as you had - but with labels in the right place

Comment: Thanks you're a savior

Comment: I Can't set action for this views from storyboard ! why ? Is there a way to set action for this views or at least image views inside ?

Comment: I Fixed The action issue. Thanks again for the solution.

Comment: what do you mean?  I have a controller with image view set up as described, and another image view on the controller - and I get the same storyboard options for all of them.**posted just as you posted your 'fixed' message!**

Comment: Sorry I forgot to make user interaction enable for them. :)